# go get github... gives GOPATH can not start ~

Tags: go, homebrew

I am trying to run:

```
$ go get github.com/scipipe/scipipe/...
```

but I am getting the error message:

```
go: GOPATH entry cannot start with shell metacharacter '~': "~/go"
```

I have tried reinstalling go but it has no effect. In fact I can't even run `version`:

```
$ go version
go: GOPATH entry cannot start with shell metacharacter '~': "~/go"
```

I am on a Mac and have installed go with Homebrew. How can this be so badly broken? Please help.

Comment: I haven't seen this before but an obvious try would be to change the `~` to `/home/username/` in the gopath. Have you tried to do so?

Comment: Nope, I would have expected that to be fixed by reinstallation though but please, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a line: (no idea how it got there)

```
export GOPATH="~/go"
```

which I changed into:

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
```

in my `.profile` file. Seems to have done the trick!